# Множественные IP на bond интерфейсе в debian

Tags: интерфейс, ip, debian

Есть настроенные bond

```
auto bond0  
iface bond0 inet static  
    address 192.168.0.5  
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    gateway 192.168.0.1  
    network 192.168.0.0  
    bond_mode 4  
    bond_miimon 100  
    bond_downdelay 200  
    bond_updelay 200  
    bond_xmit_hash_policy layer3+4  
    slaves eth0 eth1 eth2
```

Надо ему добавить еще один ip адрес - `192.168.10.5`.

Пробовал сделать

```
auto bond0:1  
iface bond0:1 inet static  
    address 192.168.10.5  
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    gateway 192.168.10.1  
    network 192.168.10.0  
    bond_mode 4  
    bond_miimon 100  
    bond_downdelay 200  
    bond_updelay 200  
    bond_xmit_hash_policy layer3+4  
    slaves eth0 eth1 eth2
```

Но в этом случае сеть не поднимается.
Есть идеи как?

Comment: @AlbertR, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
auto bond0  
iface bond0 inet static  
    address 192.168.0.5  
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    gateway 192.168.0.1  
    network 192.168.0.0  
    bond_mode 4  
    bond_miimon 100  
    bond_downdelay 200  
    bond_updelay 200  
    bond_xmit_hash_policy layer3+4  
    slaves eth0 eth1 eth2

iface bond0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.10.1
```

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению:
  
    --- cut ---  
    Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces ... (warning).  
    Reconfiguring network interfaces.../etc/network/interfaces:24: duplicate interface  
    ifdown: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"  
    /etc/network/interfaces:24: duplicate interface  
    ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
    failed.

Answer (score 0):

например, с помощью директивы `up`, в которой можно укзать команду, которая будет выполнена после поднятия интерфейса:

```
up команда
```

для вашего случая примерно так (команда добавит адрес `192.168.10.5` с маской `24` бита к интерфейсу `bond0`):

```
up ip a a 192.168.10.5/24 dev bond0
```

добавлять строку с директивой нужно где-нибудь внутрь секции, начинающейся с `iface bond0 ...`. например, между любыми из строк вашего примера.