# Проблема с загрузкой системы после добавления IPs

Tags: linux, debian, ispmanager

Здравствуйте,

после добавления в панели ISPManager 90 IP, сервер, после ребута, начал очень долго загружаться (15-20 мин). 
Через KVM видно, что загрузка зависает на этом моменте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое /etc/network/interfaces:

```html
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
auto bond0
auto bond0:0
auto bond0:1
auto bond0:2
auto bond0:3
auto bond0:4
auto bond0:5
auto bond0:6
auto bond0:7
auto bond0:8
auto bond0:9
auto bond0:10
auto bond0:11
auto bond0:12
auto bond0:13
auto bond0:14
auto bond0:15
auto bond0:16
auto bond0:17
auto bond0:18
auto bond0:19
auto bond0:20
auto bond0:21
auto bond0:22
auto bond0:23
auto bond0:24
auto bond0:25
auto bond0:26
auto bond0:27
auto bond0:28
auto bond0:29
auto bond0:30
auto bond0:31
auto bond0:32
auto bond0:33
auto bond0:34
auto bond0:35
auto bond0:36
auto bond0:37
auto bond0:38
auto bond0:39
auto bond0:40
auto bond0:41
auto bond0:42
auto bond0:43
auto bond0:44
auto bond0:45
auto bond0:46
auto bond0:47
auto bond0:48
auto bond0:49
auto bond0:50
auto bond0:51
auto bond0:52
auto bond0:53
auto bond0:54
auto bond0:55
auto bond0:56
auto bond0:57
auto bond0:58
auto bond0:59
auto bond0:60
auto bond0:61
auto bond0:62
auto bond0:63
auto bond0:64
auto bond0:65
auto bond0:66
auto bond0:67
auto bond0:68
auto bond0:69
auto bond0:70
auto bond0:71
auto bond0:72
auto bond0:73
auto bond0:74
auto bond0:75
auto bond0:76
auto bond0:77
auto bond0:78
auto bond0:79
auto bond0:80
auto bond0:81
auto bond0:82
auto bond0:83
auto bond0:84
auto bond0:85
auto bond0:86
auto bond0:87
auto bond0:88
auto bond0:89
auto bond0:90
iface eth0 inet static
 address 79.000.42.57
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 broadcast 79.000.42.255
 gateway 79.000.42.254

iface eth0 inet6 static
 address 2001:99d0:0403:0239::
 netmask 64
 dns-nameservers 2001:99d0:3:163::1
 post-up sleep 5; /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add 2001:99d0:0403:02ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
 post-up sleep 5; /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via 2001:99d0:0403:02ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del default via 2001:99d0:0403:02ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
 pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del 2001:99d0:0403:02ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
iface bond0 inet static
 address ip
 netmask 255.255.255.0
iface bond0:0 inet static
 address ip
 netmask 255.255.255.255
iface bond0:1 inet static
 address ip
 netmask 255.255.255.255
iface bond0:2 inet static
 address ip
 netmask 255.255.255.255
  
и так далее 90 IP
```

Система: Debian GNU/Linux 8.9 (jessie) x64

Панель: ISPmanager 5, последняя версия stable

Подскажите, плз, как можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот эти строки абсолютно не нужны:

```
auto bond0:0
...
auto bond0:90
```

вместе с вот этими:

```
iface bond0:0 inet static
address <ip>
netmask 255.255.255.255
...
iface bond0:90 inet static
address <ip>
netmask 255.255.255.255
```

всё-таки мы уже в двадцать первом веке живём и для работы сетевой подсистемы программы *linux* совсем не требуются прошловековые «костыли» под названием «network aliases».

вам достаточно прописать добавление адресов непосредственно в описание интерфейса:

```
iface bond0 inet static
address <ip>
netmask 255.255.255.0
# добавление адресов:
up ip a a <ip-адрес-0>/<маска-0> dev $IFACE
...
up ip a a <ip-адрес-90>/<маска-90> dev $IFACE
```

эти девяносто одну строку, кстати, можно и в отдельный скрипт вынести:

```
iface bond0 inet static
address ip
netmask 255.255.255.0
# добавление адресов:
up /путь/к/вашему/скрипту
```

и, как уже посоветовали в другом ответе, `auto bond0` лучше заменить на `allow-hotplug bond0`

---

подробности смотрите в [`man 5 interfaces`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html), [`man 8 ip`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2/ip.8.en.html) и [`man 8 ip-address`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2/ip-address.8.en.html).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте для интерфейсов вместо `auto` использовать `allow-hotplug`, с `auto` загрузка системы не пройдет, пока хоть один интерфейс не поднимется, оно будет ожидать и в случае ошибки, падать. По крайней мере в документации так расписано. Либо как вариант, один из интерфейсов у вас переименовался, если переходили на systemd, а сейчас система пытается поднять несуществующий. Но для начала сделайте то, что расписал выше, должно помочь

Comment: Заменил auto на allow-hotplug, система загрузилась быстро, но теперь панель не видит прикрепленные ip, и пинга до них нет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436973/178576